# WordPress site fails to update any plugin

Tags: wordpress, maintenance-mode

I have a small WordPress website with latest version of WP 6.1.

I update all plugin regularly and since yesterday i am not able to update any plugin as updates fails each time with below error

[image]

After this website gets stuck in Maintenance mode for about 10 minutes, which i fix by removing .maintenance file.

I have tried to update plugin several times in last 24 hours but i face same problem all the time.

I also tried turned off this setting `define( 'WP_INSTALLING', false);` based on one article without any relief.

upon checking log file error_log file it shows last log error from 15 Feb 23

```
[15-Feb-2023 16:46:38 UTC] Cron reschedule event error for hook: put_do_weekly_action, Error code: invalid_schedule, Error message: Event schedule does not exist., Data: {"schedule":"monthly","args":[],"interval":2635200}
```

I am a basic user of WP CMS any pointer to resolve this problem.

I am not sure also where i can find details related to Plugin update log

Update:

1. I tried restoring old database backup that didn't solve the problem
2. I tried restoring restoring all file but kept the latest DB that didn't solve the problem

Solution: When i restored full backup (database & files) in new different folder & then restored latest copy of database then only i was able to update all plugins without any problem.

It seems some file was corrupt which was causing the problem which i was not able to point as no error was logged.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to deactivate & delete the plugin and then re-install the latest version.

Comment: Is that happening to only that plugin or for all plugins?

Comment: @Shreyasikhar26, Update fails for all plugin, deactivating  doesn't work. very confusing as i tried multiple solutions. something is creating problem but no error is generated in log i even turned on debug mode but no error was logged.

Comment: I think the cron is not running correctly on your WordPress installation. Can you please check by adding `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in your wp-config.php to see plugin updates works or not.

Reference: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wp-cron/